# making a variable negative for animation

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-animate

I have a variable that I set up and I want to animate the margin-top to a negative version of that value.  I have it set up like so:

```
var 850_staff_CONTAINER_ht = $('#850_staff_CONTAINER').height();

$("#launcher").click(function() {

$("#850_staff_CONTAINER").animate({
    marginTop: '-'850_staff_CONTAINER_ht
}, 300);


$("#profile_850_HEADER").animate({
    marginTop: 120
}, 300);
$("#profile_850_BIO").delay(120).animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 450);
$("#profile_850_EDU").delay(220).animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 450);
$("#profile_850_CONTACT").delay(320).animate({
    marginTop: 10
}, 450);


});
```

any help here would be great.

Comment: `var 850_staff_CONTAINER_ht` is illegal syntax; variable names cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the variable 850_staff_CONTAINER_ht negative?

First variables can not start with a number. In HTML4, element ids can not start with a number. I put the 850 on the end to make it a valid variable name.

Multiply it

```
var staff_CONTAINER_ht_850 = $('#850_staff_CONTAINER').height();

 marginTop: staff_CONTAINER_ht_850 * -1;
```